# Android Room Migration test fails, although nothing changed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, database-migration

I am trying to test a Room migration, but the test always fails. There is not even a change in the model. I only increase the version number and the migration is empty - the test still fails. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Let's say we have an entity `EntityExample`, with two columns `a` and `b`. The primary key is composed of both `a` and `b`, and we have indices for both columns. The code looks like:

```java
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"a", "b"}, indices = {@Index("a"), @Index("b")})
public class EntityExample {
    @NonNull public Long a;
    @NonNull public Long b;
}
```

Further, our database in version 1:

```java
@Database(version=1,entities={EntityExample.class})
public abstract class DBExample extends RoomDatabase {
}
```

and in version 2:

```java
@Database(version=2,entities={EntityExample.class})
public abstract class DBExample extends RoomDatabase {
}
```

Also, there are the migrations:

```java
public class MigrationExample {
    public final static Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

        }
    };
}
```

To access the schema in tests, in the build.gradle was added:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        // Adds exported schema location as test app assets.
        debug.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
}
```

And, finally, the test:

```java
@Config(sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MigrationExampleTest {

    @Rule
    public MigrationTestHelper helper;

    public MigrationExampleTest() {
        helper = new MigrationTestHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
                DBExample.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory());
    }

    @Test
    public void migrationTest() throws IOException {

        SupportSQLiteDatabase dbV1 = helper.createDatabase("migration-test", 1);
        dbV1.close();

        DBExample dbV2 = Room.databaseBuilder(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                DBExample.class,
                "migration-test")
                .addMigrations(MigrationExample.MIGRATION_1_2)
                .build();
        dbV2.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        dbV2.close();
    }

}
```

The test fails on the line `dbV2.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();` with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: EntityExample(....EntityExample).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='EntityExample', columns={a=Column{name='a', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, b=Column{name='b', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=2, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[Index{name='index_EntityExample_a', unique=false, columns=[a]}, Index{name='index_EntityExample_b', unique=false, columns=[b]}]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='EntityExample', columns={a=Column{name='a', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, b=Column{name='b', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=null}
```

As you can see (when scrolling the test output to the right), the *indices* part is missing in the found TableInfo. Also, the *primaryKeyPosition* for `b` differs between 1 and 2. I don't understand why, I don't know what exactly causes the test to fail, and I don't know how to fix this. Running the app works, no exceptions are thrown. I checked the schemas, they are completely the same except for the updated version number (see https://justpaste.it/68l2b and https://justpaste.it/3r45p). However, the test fails!

Comment: I have the same problem. Using SQL statements to create indices doesn't work because they doesn't show up in the TableInfo, so my migration test always fails too.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't yet, you can check this good article on migration testing : https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/testing-room-migrations-be93cdb0d975

Then, in your migration you have to actually migrate the database, execute the SQL to go from 1 to 2,  by creating indices for example.

Room handles migration chaining, structure integrity and testing, but not the migration itself.
In the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions they do migrations of their database, you should do the same.

Comment: how do I migrate a database when nothing changed between v1 and v2?

Comment: As seen in your error messages, you have added Indices on fields a and b of EntityExample, that is the difference. You need to make the SQL to create those indices.
If you just want to wipe out the previous data structure, just rollback version to 1, uninstall and reinstall the app, and start over :)

Comment: I have not added anything in v2. Sorry if I did not make this clear enough: nothing in `EntityExample` was changed between v1 and v2. The indices already existed in v1.

Comment: So there is a database stored without indices, wich needs to be removed. If you are working on examples and tutorials, just uninstall your app and reinstall on v1.  If it is production, just do what room wants by creatibg indices, it may be a change in room version.

Comment: The stored database already has the indices. At least it should have, because `EntityExample` did not change. This is not about getting an app to run or any production app - its about getting a test to succeed. And for this, not even a stored DB is used. Only the schemas are used. And the schemas are exactly the same.

Comment: I think you should look at the generated json files of the databases, there is one for each version. There should be the actual difference. You can also use the device explorer of android studio to look at the actual database on the device by pulling the file, and check for those indices. But I think the best for now in your case is to restart fresh from version one, and look at the  medium.com tutorial about migration testing in room.

Comment: the generated json files are exactly the same, except for the version number. see https://justpaste.it/68l2b and https://justpaste.it/3r45p

Comment: So there is a problem with an existing database on the device. Have you tried to remove the app totally ? And if they are the same, why to you create a new version then ? Juste stick with 1.

Comment: Again, this is not about any existing databases or any existing applications. It is about getting a test to run. I want to test a migration, but the test is failing. The migration (doing nothing) itself is working.